# Remove i486 kernel (retain i686 kernel) after install

Tags: linux, debian, updates, kernel

I'm repurposing an older 32-bit machine. After a Debian install, I have the following GRUb entries:

```
Linux 3.2.0-4-486
Linux 3.2.0-4-686
```

I don't need the i486 kernel.

I have been deleting the i486 kernel manually and then running `grub2-mkconfig -o ...`. But I suspect its not a "clean" removal, and it may show back up sometime in the future after an update.

Is there a way to "cleanly" remove the 3.2.0-4-486 kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out the package for the extra kernel:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

And then remove the package installation from system:

```
apt-get remove <package name>
```